# Subsequent events not firing

Tags: jquery, event-handling

I know I am missing something simple, but this is my first jQuery project and I'm just not finding the issue. When I close the code block ( }); ) for the #AddTopTier button, nothing else works. I can move the close to just before the end of all the events and things work well, but that makes every event dependent on the proceeding event - which creates problems.

I've create this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tLx8epqr/1/

For those who don't want to go there, here are some details.

I have this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i = 1
    var s = 1

    //Add code for Tier display
    $('#AddTopTier').click(function(){
        var tierStr="<DIV ID='divTier"+i+"' style='width: 400px; border:2px dotted #0099CC; padding: 5px;'>"
            tierStr=tierStr + "<INPUT TYPE='text' size='20' NAME='inputName"+i+"' ID='inputName"+i+"' VALUE='"+ $('#NewTierName').val()+ "'></INPUT>"
            tierStr=tierStr + "<INPUT TYPE='text' ID='Tier"+i+"' NAME='Tier"+i+"' CLASS='tierScore"+i+"' VALUE='30' SIZE='2' MAXLENGTH='3' DISABLED></INPUT>"
            tierStr=tierStr + "<INPUT TYPE='button' ID='btnUpTier"+i+"' CLASS='upTier' VALUE='+'></INPUT>"
            tierStr=tierStr + "<INPUT TYPE='button' ID='btnDownTier"+i+"' CLASS='dwnTier' VALUE='-'></INPUT>"
            tierStr=tierStr + "&nbsp;&nbsp;<INPUT TYPE='button' ID='btnAddSkill"+i+"' CLASS='btnAddSkill' VALUE='Add Skill'></INPUT>"
            tierStr=tierStr + "</DIV><p/>"
        i++;
        $('#Contents').append(tierStr);
    //End Tier display
    }); //This is the issue. Closing the code block here prevents the next code block from executing. I can move this to the end, but that creates and unacceptable dependency.

//Add code for Skill display
$(".btnAddSkill").unbind().click(function(){

//make sure there are enough Skill Points
if(parseFloat($('#SkillPts').val()) < 1){
        alert("You don't have enough skill points.")
    }
else
    {
//find the name of the div and strip out 'div' to leave the tier name
var tier = ($(this).parent('div').attr('id'));
    tier = tier.replace("div","");

    var skillStr="<br/> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <INPUT TYPE='text' size='20' ID='skillName"+i+"' VALUE=''></INPUT>"
    skillStr=skillStr + "<INPUT TYPE='text' NAME='Skill"+s+"' ID='Skill"+s+"' CLASS='skill"+tier+"' VALUE='' SIZE='2' MAXLENGTH='3' DISABLED></INPUT>"
    skillStr=skillStr + "<INPUT TYPE='button' ID='btnUpSkill"+s+"' CLASS='upSkill' VALUE='+'></INPUT>"
    skillStr=skillStr + "<INPUT TYPE='button' ID='btnDownSkill"+s+"' CLASS='dwnSkill' VALUE='-'></INPUT>"

//append this to the div associated with the appropriate Tier for display
$(this).parent('div').append(skillStr);

//find the name of the div and strip out 'div' to leave the tier name
var tier = ($(this).parent('div').attr('id'));
    tier = tier.replace("div","");

//Find the skill's Tier Score, add 5        
   $('#Skill'+s).val(parseFloat($('#'+tier).val())+5);

//Decrease the available Skill Points by 1
$('#SkillPts').val(parseFloat($('#SkillPts').val())-1);
    s++
    }
//End Skill display
}); //...and so on...
```

As stated, I expected the closure of the #AddTopTier event to allow the .btnAddSkill event execute, but this is not happening.

(BTW: I know this is not graceful code - as I said, it is my first attempt - kind of go big or go home. This question is one of the steps in getting it cleaned up.)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to learn about how event binding works. Events will be bound to the element based on the selector supplied once the page elements got loaded, since we wrote it inside document ready handler. During that time(immediately after elements got loaded) if the elements matches with the selector not found, then that event handlers will be of no use. That is your case, you bound events to the elements which will be added in the future. So your code wont work. In that case you have to use `event delegation` to bind the events. It uses event bubbling under the hood to trigger the event. It would be a bigger story, if i start to write about event delegation fully here. So please read about it [here](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

And your working code goes [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/tLx8epqr/3/)

Comment: Looks like the .on() function is just what I needed! Yes, I need to develop a better understanding of even binding - much different than server-side stuff (where I'm more familiar). I'm trying to get enough reputation to up your answer. When I do, it'll show. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

hello your solution!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i = 1
    var s = 1

    //Add code for Tier display
    $('#AddTopTier').click(function(){
        var tierStr="<DIV ID='divTier"+i+"' style='width: 400px; border:2px dotted #0099CC; padding: 5px;'>"
            tierStr=tierStr + "<INPUT TYPE='text' size='20' NAME='inputName"+i+"' ID='inputName"+i+"' VALUE='"+ $('#NewTierName').val()+ "'></INPUT>"
            tierStr=tierStr + "<INPUT TYPE='text' ID='Tier"+i+"' NAME='Tier"+i+"' CLASS='tierScore"+i+"' VALUE='30' SIZE='2' MAXLENGTH='3' DISABLED></INPUT>"
            tierStr=tierStr + "<INPUT TYPE='button' ID='btnUpTier"+i+"' CLASS='upTier' VALUE='+'></INPUT>"
            tierStr=tierStr + "<INPUT TYPE='button' ID='btnDownTier"+i+"' CLASS='dwnTier' VALUE='-'></INPUT>"
            tierStr=tierStr + "&nbsp;&nbsp;<INPUT TYPE='button' ID='btnAddSkill"+i+"' CLASS='btnAddSkill' VALUE='Add Skill'></INPUT>"
            tierStr=tierStr + "</DIV><p/>"
        i++;
        $('#Contents').append(tierStr);
    //End Tier display
    });

    //Add code for Skill display
    $("#Contents").on( "click", ".btnAddSkill", function( event ) {

    //make sure there are enough Skill Points
    if(parseFloat($('#SkillPts').val()) < 1){
            alert("You don't have enough skill points.")
        }
    else
        {
    //find the name of the div and strip out 'div' to leave the tier name
    var tier = ($(this).parent('div').attr('id'));
        tier = tier.replace("div","");

        var skillStr="<br/> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <INPUT TYPE='text' size='20' ID='skillName"+i+"' VALUE=''></INPUT>"
        skillStr=skillStr + "<INPUT TYPE='text' NAME='Skill"+s+"' ID='Skill"+s+"' CLASS='skill"+tier+"' VALUE='' SIZE='2' MAXLENGTH='3' DISABLED></INPUT>"
        skillStr=skillStr + "<INPUT TYPE='button' ID='btnUpSkill"+s+"' CLASS='upSkill' VALUE='+'></INPUT>"
        skillStr=skillStr + "<INPUT TYPE='button' ID='btnDownSkill"+s+"' CLASS='dwnSkill' VALUE='-'></INPUT>"

    //append this to the div associated with the appropriate Tier for display
    $(this).parent('div').append(skillStr);

    //find the name of the div and strip out 'div' to leave the tier name
    var tier = ($(this).parent('div').attr('id'));
        tier = tier.replace("div","");

    //Find the skill's Tier Score, add 5        
       $('#Skill'+s).val(parseFloat($('#'+tier).val())+5);

    //Decrease the available Skill Points by 1
    $('#SkillPts').val(parseFloat($('#SkillPts').val())-1);
        s++
        }
    //End Skill display
    });

//*****Tier Adjustments*****
    //Increase Tier scores
    $("#Contents").on( "click", ".upTier", function( event ) {

    //strip out 'btnUp' from the button name, leaving the Tier name
    var tier = (this.id.replace('btnUp',""));

    //make sure there are enough Skill Points
    //Determine the high skill penalty
        function upSkillMod(currVal){
            var tierMod
            var currVal = parseFloat(currVal)
                if(currVal == 50 || currVal == 55 || currVal == 60){
                    tierMod = 2
                    }
                else if(currVal == 65 || currVal == 70){
                    tierMod = 3
                    }
                else if (currVal > 70){
                    tierMod = 4
                    }
                else{
                    tierMod = 1
                    }
                return tierMod
                };
    //Update the skill points to reflect 2 per tier, plus high skill penalty
        var oldScore = parseFloat($('.upTier').siblings('#'+tier).val())
        var newTierScore = parseFloat(2 * (upSkillMod(oldScore)))
        var currPts = parseFloat($('#SkillPts').val())

        if(currPts > newTierScore || currPts == newTierScore){
            newTierScore = currPts - newTierScore
                $('#SkillPts').val(newTierScore)                

            //add 5 to the old value, display value
            var newScore = oldScore + 5
                $('.upTier').siblings('#'+tier).val(newScore);

            //increase any Skills which may be under the Tier
            $(this).siblings(".skill"+tier).each(function(){
                //extract the name
                skillNum = $(this).prop('name')
                    var currVal = parseFloat($('#'+skillNum).val()) + 5;
                        $('#'+skillNum).val(currVal)
                });
                }
            else{
                    alert("You don't have enough skill points.")    
                };

    //Decrease Skill Points by 2 points times skillMod
        function upSkillMod(currVal){
            var tierMod
            var currVal = parseFloat(currVal)
                if(currVal == 55 || currVal == 60 || currVal == 65){
                        tierMod = 2
                        }
                    else if(currVal == 70 || currVal == 75){
                        tierMod = 3
                        }
                    else if (currVal > 70){
                        tierMod = 4
                        }
                    else{
                        tierMod = 1
                        }
                    return tierMod
            };
        //Update the skill points to reflect 2 per tier, plus high skill penalty
        var oldScore = parseFloat($('.upTier').siblings('#'+tier).val())
        var newScore = oldScore - 5
        var newTierScore = parseFloat(2 * (upSkillMod(newScore)))
            newTierScore = parseFloat(($('#SkillPts').val())) - newTierScore
                $('#SkillPts').val(newTierScore)
            });

    //Decrease Tier scores
    $("#Contents").on( "click", ".dwnTier", function( event ) {

        //strip out 'btnDown' from the button name, leaving the Tier name

        var tier = (this.id.replace('btnDown',""));
        //make sure that the score does not go below 25

        if($('.dwnTier').siblings('#'+tier).val() <= 25){
                alert("Tiers cannot be taken below 25.")
            }
        else
            {
            //get the value of the related tier and add 5, display value
            var newScore = parseFloat($('.upTier').siblings('#'+tier).val()) - 5    
                $('.upTier').siblings('#'+tier).val(newScore);

            //increase any Skills which may be under the Tier
                $(this).siblings(".skill"+tier).each(function(){
                    //extract the name
                    skillNum = $(this).prop('name')
                    var currVal = parseFloat($('#'+skillNum).val()) - 5;
                    $('#'+skillNum).val(currVal)                    
                });
            //Decrease the available Skill Points by 2 points times skillMod
            function dwnSkillMod(currVal){
                var tierMod
                        var currVal = parseFloat(currVal)
                            if(currVal == 50 || currVal == 55 || currVal == 60){
                                tierMod = 2
                                }
                            else if(currVal == 65 || currVal == 70){
                                tierMod = 3
                                }
                            else if (currVal > 70){
                                tierMod = 4
                                }
                            else{
                                tierMod = 1
                                }
                            return tierMod
            };
        //Update the skill points to reflect 2 per tier, plus high skill penalty
        var newTierScore = parseFloat(2 * (dwnSkillMod(newScore)))
            newTierScore = parseFloat(($('#SkillPts').val())) + newTierScore
                $('#SkillPts').val(newTierScore)
            };
        });

//*****Skill Adjustments*****
    //Increase Skill scores
    $("#Contents").on( "click", ".upSkill", function( event ) {

        //strip out 'btnUp' from the button name, leaving the Skill name
        var skill = (this.id.replace('btnUp',""));

        //make sure there are enough Skill Points

//!!!Need to validate points versus total cost
    //make sure there are enough Skill Points
    //Determine the high skill penalty
        function upSkillMod(currVal){
            var skillMod
            var currVal = parseFloat(currVal)
                if(currVal == 50 || currVal == 55 || currVal == 60){
                    skillMod = 2
                    }
                else if(currVal == 65 || currVal == 70){
                    skillMod = 3
                    }
                else if (currVal > 70){
                    skillMod = 4
                    }
                else{
                    skillMod = 1
                    }
                return skillMod
                };
    //Update the skill points to reflect 2 per tier, plus high skill penalty
        var oldScore = parseFloat($('.upSkill').siblings('#'+skill).val())
        var newSkillScore = parseFloat(1 * (upSkillMod(oldScore)))
        var currPts = parseFloat($('#SkillPts').val())


        if(currPts > newSkillScore || currPts == newSkillScore){
            newSkillScore = currPts - newSkillScore
                $('#SkillPts').val(newSkillScore)               

                    //add 5 to the old value, display value
                    var newScore = oldScore + 5
                    $('.upTier').siblings('#'+skill).val(newScore);
                }
            else{
                    alert("You don't have enough skill points.")    
                };
            });
//****

    //Decrease Skill scores
    $("#Contents").on( "click", ".dwnSkill", function( event ) {

        //strip out 'btnDown' from the button name, leaving the Skill name
        var skill = (this.id.replace('btnDown',""));

//!!!Validate to make sure the skills do not drop below associated tier 
  var skillComp = $('.dwnSkill').siblings('#'+skill).val();
  var tierName = "#Tier"+(this.id.replace('btnDownSkill',""));
  var tierComp = $(tierName).val()

    if (skillComp <= 30){
                alert("Skills cannot be taken below 30.")
            }
        else if (skillComp - 5 == tierComp){
            alert("Skills cannot drop equal to or lower than the Tier.")
            }
        else
            {
                //get the value of the related tier and add 5, display value        
                $('.dwnSkill').siblings('#'+skill).val(parseFloat($('.dwnSkill').siblings('#'+skill).val()) - 5);

                //Increase the available Skill Points by 1
                $('#SkillPts').val(parseFloat($('#SkillPts').val())+1);
            }
    });
    }); 
//  }); 
//});
```

Comment: Thank you. Looks like .on() is my solution. Once I have enough reputation, the +1 I gave you will show!